# База данных, Word, Escel

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте. У меня есть бланк Excel документа (счёт и акт), как мне его распечатать и сохранить в Word? Значения полей надо брать из Базы данных (Query).

Answer (score 2):

Использовать генераторы отчетов такие как например QuickReport, FastReport, RaveReport и их компоненты. RaveReport - стандартный, поставляется с Делфи.